# Tabbed Reports in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have been working on reports in Sql Server Reporting services and I am trying to create a tabbed report.

I wish to have a main report which read in parameter details from the user then in the report there are tabs to other reports which use the same parameter details entered by the user on the main report.

Anyone got any idea how to go about this ? Have tried creating subreports but it doesnt quite create that overall feel of a tabbed report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no native feature for tabs, but you can create that functionality with a combination of existing features.

1. Add textboxes along the top which will be your tab names.
2. Add a hidden parameter which will track which tab is selected. Have the first value selected by default.
3. Add an action to each textbox which goes back to the report with a specific value passed to the parameter.
4. Add an expression to the border properties of each textbox so that you can visually see which one is selected. For example you can remove the bottom border for the selected tab.
5. Add a visibility expression to everything else on the report so that the items only show up when their tab is selected.

Now each time you click a tab, it will refresh the report and show that tab highlighted along with the content it contains. It's a lot of steps, but it's the best workaround I've found for this feature.

Comment: Is there a way then to get the tabbed report to apply the same parameters to that chosen by the main report ? Need the tabs to flow in with the main report

Comment: Yes, when you link to another report using a textbox action you do have the option of passing along any parameters that it uses.